# Exercises for mathematical logic and model theory

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory, book-recommendation, online-resources

I'm computer science student and looking for exercises (with solutions) for mathematical logic and model theory. Are there any books, notes, online resources etc. you can recommend?

Comment: I always recommend Marker's Model Theory. I bet many of the more challenging problems have solutions somewhere on this website.

Comment: [Software Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/) might be a resource worth investigating. It has exercises but doesn't have answers. That said, since the exercises are to produce Coq proofs answers are less necessary (i.e. if you correctly answer, you know). You can almost certainly find answers online anyway, and you may be able to request them from the authors. This doesn't cover model theory (at least not in an obvious or traditional manner).

Answer (score 0):

The Cori - Lascar is perfect for a computer science student :

[Mathematical Logic](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/mathematical-logic-9780198500513?cc=us&lang=en&)